# How to use GNU atomic memory access functions in keil

Tags: c, keil

I want to use GCC built-in functions like `__sync_fetch_and_add`, but I compile my code with Keil, if I use these functions in my code, it will be show err like this:

```
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol __sync_fetch_and_add_4 (referred from XXXX.o).
```

I found there are some describes with `GNU atomic memory access functions` in [Keil's documents](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359125006834.htm),  so I guess that keil may be support these functions, but I don't know how to use them. Should I include some header files or add some config in keil?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but the link seems to be about ARM DS-5, which is a separate compiler i.e. not the same as Keil's MDK. So the documentation doesn't apply.

Implementing those functions is not super hard; if all else fails I would look at the compiler output from GCC, and just re-implement it.

Alternatively read up on the `LDREX`/`STREX` instructions and those for memory barriers, and have fun! :)

*UPDATE*: I think `__sync_fetch_and_add_4()` is new, but Keil only supports GCC's older suite of built-ins. Notice that `__sync_fetch_and_add_4` does not appear in the list of functions they say that they support. [This GCC manual page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_concurrency_impl.html) says:

> Prior to GCC 4.7 the older `__sync` intrinsics were used. An example of an undefined symbol from the use of `__sync_fetch_and_add` on an unsupported host is a missing reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4`.

So it seems Keil is tracking a pretty old version of GCC? On the other hand, I do see  `__sync_fetch_and_add()` in the list, and I guess that "magically" generates a call to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4()` if used on a 32-bit quantity. Weird.

Comment: sorry，it's my fault, I updated the link. There are records too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply，now I’m sure that these functions actually built-in keil, function __sync_fetch_and_add_4()  maybe is redefined.  I still can’t find a solution to this problem, l’ll keep looking, thank you again.

Comment: I still haven't made any progress，and my project is a bit urgent recently, so instead of these atomic functions, I used interrupt lock mechanism. I'll check the problem when I'm a little free. Thank you very much for your answer. 